# Neither null nor type check detecting destroyed object/component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an issue for which I've found a workaround, but can't understand why Unity isn't working the way I expect, or what I'm doing wrong. Basically, I am referencing a renderer component of a destroyed object in a script (long after it's been destroyed), and neither null checks nor type checks let me know it's destroyed.

I have a script that's modifying the shaders on some objects temporarily so I can apply effects on to them; when the effects are done it puts the materials/shaders back the way they were.

It happened that I was swapping out a character's weapon in the same frame I began one of these effects, so the script wound up with a reference to the renderer of a destroyed object (the old weapon). Many frames later when the effect was to finish, it naturally err'd out.

[image]

I tried a type check first to see if the reference was still to a renderer -- no luck. Unity's doc says a null check should work, but it still doesn't.

`if (pair.Key != null && pair.Key is Renderer renderer) { renderer.materials = pair.Value; }`

I get:

`MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'SkinnedMeshRenderer' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.`

`activeInHierarchy` likewise does not work.

Adding a DestroyImmediate to the code where I destroy the object works fine; the object isn't there by the time the effect starts, so the reference is never made. However, that only solves this one problem, and not other such cases.

Can anyone tell me how to check properly for references to destroyed objects or components, or if I'm doing something wrong in my checking? Should I be referencing the gameObject instead of the renderer component or something like that?

EDIT:
Since a commenter asked for it, here's a gist of the full code for the effect. The destruction is happening outside this, as it's totally unrelated.
https://gist.github.com/jackphelps/f507d949a84c53457f570c5009bcb6d4

SOLVED -- SORT OF?
I changed the dictionary to store the renderer's game object instead of the renderer, and as expected a simple null check worked for detecting a destroyed object. I'd *love* to know why it doesn't work on the renderer, and if there's a proper way to check!

Comment: Are you removing the key from your dictionary when you destroy the object?

Comment: If you notice the screenshot is off a list but my code shows a dictionary: my reference is stored in a dictionary; since unity won't serialize them, I added lists tracking the same references as the dictionary key/value pairs so I could see what was going on.

Comment: And why are you using a dictionary to change renderer.materials? You can directly reference that from the key. There's no need to temporarily store that to a value.

Comment: @ErikOverflow I'm not -- the item destruction is totally unrelated to the effect, the effect is just picking the item up because the destruction happened earlier in the same frame. So I need a way to make sure the dictionary is still valid when the final bit of the effect is run.

Comment: I'm changing the materials, the reference stored is to the original materials. I need different ones for the temporary effects.

Comment: You will need to provide more code for this context. Where you are creating your dictionary. What else affects the dictionary, etc. There is no way for anyone to reproduce this error with what you've provided.

Comment: ok, wasn't saying it was a bug and needed reproduction, just curious how to properly check for a destroyed component. I have a feeling if I was storing a reference to the gameobject instead of the component, this wouldn't be a problem, so I'll probably try that out. Still curious how to do this right; I'll update the post with the full effect code.

Comment: @ErikOverflow updated with a gist of the code

Comment: @ErikOverflow see 2nd update -- null check works fine (as expected) with the renderer's game object. Still can't figure out how to check the component. Thanks for looking! Curious if you have any thoughts :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I could find to solve this was to store a reference to the renderer's gameObject rather than to the renderer component itself. In this case, a simple null check at the end of the script works fine, as expected.

I'm not accepting this answer because it still doesn't tell me how to check for a component's presence when the game object was removed ¯(°_o)/¯

Comment: This is likely because Destroy occurs at the end of the frame. If you destroy the renderer's gameObject, the renderer doesn't know that it's been destroyed until the end of the frame. The gameObject reference will return null, but renderer will continue to reference the component until the destroy is completed.  The reason DestroyImmediate works is because it cleans up all dirty references immediately.

Comment: @ErikOverflow You're not understanding -- as I said, the effect ends (and the reference to the renderer is used) many frames after the reference is created. I'm trying to make the effect safe even when a renderer it's referred to has been destroyed at any point between its start and end. You could reproduce this by simply referencing a gameobject's renderer component, then at some point later destroying the gameobject, then at some point after that, trying to verify whether the renderer exists or not.

Comment: I said initially that destroyimmediate does work for this situation, and I understand why -- the reference is never made in the first place -- but that doesn't handle other cases where the object could have been destroyed while the effect is running. Fortunately, the solution here does.